# modeling a building from one cube

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface, workflow

I wanted to build a building like the picture and what I did was putting two cubes on top of each other . I want know how this can be made from one cube I mean start from one cube and extrude or ...
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Enter edit mode
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to make a loop cut across the mesh.
3. Repeat in other direction
4. Select face and extrude it upwards(<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: how do you make these videos?

Comment: @pluke You can use either [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) (@gandalf3's suggestion) or [gifcam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) cegton's suggestion. I used keypose for the shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

In *Edit Mode* select the upper face and snap the cursor to it (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*).
[image]

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the extrusion. Confirm the operation with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
[image]

Extrude once more along z axis. Press <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd> and confirm the transformation.
[image]

Now select the whole extruded element and place it wherever you like, using <kbd>G</kbd> and choosing the axis you like.
[image]

And here it is.
[image]

Comment: you can also extrude faces like that using inset. select the face(s) and "i", then move mouse to change size.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to mess with the topology of the lower part of the building, you can build them separately, select both, and join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

[image: Join Meshes]

Another option is to select the top face and duplicated it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

[image: Duplicate]

You will then be able to edit the different parts with complete flexibility, with no fear of ruining your work on the other parts of the building.

[image: Edit]