# How do I select a square area on a cube and extrude it into the plane to add depth?

Tags: mesh

How do I select a square area on a cube and extrude it into the plane to add depth? I need to make a hole in a cube but I can't affect the cube edges.

Comment: inset the face then extrude inside

Comment: how do you inset?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24423/12

Answer (score 3):

select the face click <kbd>i</kbd> and move to resize the face

then press <kbd>e</kbd> and move inside the cube

[image]

Comment: is there anyway to do this with a plane u place on the cube?

Comment: you can edit the question and add screenshot so i can get an idea

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev there is Boolean modifier you can use to cut holes in object with intersection , but it may generate a bad mesh